# Continuous dependence. Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^l\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^l,$ $n=0, 1, 2, ...$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i need help for this exercise. I do not know how to start.

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^l\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^l,$ $n=0, 1, 2, ...$ continuous such that for all $(t_0,x_0)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^l$ the solution of
\begin{equation} x'=f_n(t,x), \ x(t_0)=x_0 \ (*)
\end{equation} is unique. Suppose also that $f_n$ converges to $f_0$ uniformly in the compact parts of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^l.$ Given $t_0<t_1$, prove that the sets $A_n=A_n(t_0,t_1)$ formed by the $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^l$ such that the solution $\varphi_n(t,t_0,x_0)$ of $(*)$ is defined for $t=t_1$ is an open; also show that if $A_0\neq\emptyset$ then $A_n\neq \emptyset$ for all $n$ big enough.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For elementary/homework/computation questions of this form, we generally ask that you show any progress you've made and you point out *specifically* where you are stuck. We want to help you understand the problem; we don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: We know that $\varphi_n(t,t_0,x_0)$ is defined in a set of the form $(a,b)\times\Omega$, with $\Omega$ open. But I do not know how it is related to the $A_n$.